# Getting a RootDoc in jdk11

Tags: java, javadoc, java-11, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am trying to test out some code that works with Java Doc, it is used under the maven-javadoc-plugin. I am trying to get it to work under jdk11. I am after an implementation of `RootDoc` which I can use when running tests.

Currently the tests use [EasyDoclet](https://github.com/4thline/seamless/blob/master/javadoc/src/main/java/org/seamless/javadoc/EasyDoclet.java) which gives me a `RootDoc` like so:

```
EasyDoclet easyDoclet = new EasyDoclet(new File("dir"), "com.foo.bar");
RootDoc rootDoc = easyDoclet.getRootDoc()
```

However I could not get this to work under jdk11.

The first issue I had was tools.jar is missing so I changed my `pom.xml` to have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seamless</groupId>
    <artifactId>seamless-javadoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
<!-- maybe this will get what ever was in tools.jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.olivergondza</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jdk-tools-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This lead to many instances of:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javadoc/PublicMessager
```

The [PublicMessager](https://github.com/4thline/seamless/blob/master/javadoc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/javadoc/PublicMessager.java) class seems to exist to make public some constructors, I am not sure why it exists under the `com.sun.tools` package. I tried to make a copy of this class:
public static class PublicMessager extends

```
com.sun.tools.javadoc.main.Messager {

    public PublicMessager(Context context, String s) {
        super(context, s);
    }

    public PublicMessager(Context context, String s, PrintWriter printWriter, PrintWriter printWriter1, PrintWriter printWriter2) {
        super(context, s, printWriter, printWriter1, printWriter2);
    }
}
```

And the error message changes to:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.fun.javadoc.FooBar$PublicMessager (in unnamed module @0x4abdb505) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javadoc.main.Messager (in module jdk.javadoc) because module jdk.javadoc does not export com.sun.tools.javadoc.main to unnamed module @0x4abdb50
```

I exposed `jdk.javadoc` to the unnamed module using:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <argLine>--add-opens=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This meant that my custom version of `PublicMessager` would no longer have the errors shown however the version from seamless under `com.sun.tools` could not be found. I made my own version of `EasyDoclet` which used my `PublicMessager` however it turned out that the following two classes are missing:

```
import com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool;
import com.sun.tools.javadoc.ModifierFilter;
```

At this point I am not sure what to do. halp!

Perhaps an alternative would be to instead find the jdk11 equivalent of `RootDoc` which I think is `DocletEnvironment` and then some how get an implementation of that, I have no idea how to get an implementation of `DocletEnvironment`.

Comment: Have you considered moving to the supported API for javadoc instead of using undocumented/unsupported internal classes. Here's the API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/module-summary.html

Comment: I am giving it a go, however it is not easy for example if I wanted to get the documentation of a `@tag` i could just do `FieldDoc#tags("tagName")` and then call `Tag#text`. In this supported API I think I would need to implement my own version of `DocTreeVisitor` which seems excessive.